# Connection between PC and android phone

Tags: android, vb.net

I'm doing a college project about food ordering system.

The way to make an order : User make an order on their own food and then the order will send to the system (pc) in order to generate a payment.

How do make this works? I means the connection. Maybe thru WI-FI? or use local connection something~ How pc will know when user made an order on their phone?

By the way, i'm using VB.net for system(Visual Studio) and java for android (Android studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to make a connection to the computer over wifi, bluetooth, whatever works best for your situation. The PC can only know an order is made depending on how you code it, so, you'll need to figure out what exactly you want to do

If you had access to it it'd be cool to implement it with NFC so you create your order wherever you want, and when you're ready to place your order and pay you just hold your phone up to a reader on the PC and it places the order and charges you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider just writing to a database from the android device and then from the VB.NET app poll the database for orders and when a new one arrives pull it up.  You could use a key such as a GUID, username/password, etc. to make sure that the order submitted from one phone matches the order on your screen.  Or...if you had access you could incorporate a barcode that would be cool...return the user a barcode that can be scanned at the terminal to bring up their order on the screen, but not sure you have access to that.

Check out the following link, it appears that "McDonalds" in Australia already does something like this.

https://mcdonalds.com.au/mobile-ordering/how-it-works